# Is it possible to add a maybee clause to a xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

So as the title sugests, is it possible to add a optional locator to the xpath?

lets say I have a html structure like so

```
<div>
   <h2>Some Text</h2>
   <h2><span>Some Text</span></h2>

</div>
```

Now, I want to be able to select both those h2 tags containing the text "Some Text" so for expamle `//div//h2[text() ='Some Text']` only result in the first one. Is it some way to add a optional parameter to the xpath like `//div//h2/?span[text() ='Some Text']` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid selecting text nodes: it's usually better to use the string-value of the element nodes. In this case

```
//h2[. = "Some Text"]
```

does what you want.

Comment: Okey had no idea you could do that, and with this way it ignores if the text is in a child element? can i use normalize-space and translate on this aswell?

Comment: Yes. Any operation that expects a string and is given an element node will extract the string value of the element, that is, the concatenation of its descendant text nodes.